# Fancybox stopped autoplaying videos in Chrome

Tags: jquery, fancybox

There's a similar thread, but the suggestion proposed didn't work out for me.

My Fancybox plugin stopped autoplaying Youtube videos for Chrome. However, Edge and Firefox keep working normally. What I do to autoplay videos is just adding autoplay=1 at the end of the video link.

To add a video to my page while using Fancybox, whenever I create a new post in Wordpress I basically click on "Add Media", paste the URL on the field and click on Insert.

The code I get is basically this:

```
<a class="fancybox-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1DNf-pcFE8?autoplay=1">
  <img src="http://vejaumbomfilme.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/onde-os-fracos-não-tem-vez-play-trailer.png" alt="" width="750" height="331" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2081" />
</a>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: This isn't a fancybox issue, but a Chrome one. Since the latest update to Chrome the rules which allow a video to autoplay have been significantly tightened: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: You are using v2? Maybe try the latest version

Comment: Janis, do you also use Fancybox? If so, is it working normally to you when you use Chrome?